# Windows Service never calls OnStop() and OnShutdown() method during shutdown

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a simple windows service and I need to do some operation when either service is stopped or machine is shutdown. See sample code below:

```
namespace SimpleService
{
    class TestService : ServiceBase
    {
        private string path = "<pathtologfile>\\TestServiceLog.txt";
        public TestService()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "TestService";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
           
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("TestService Stopped.");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            OnStop();
        }
    }
}
```

If I start/stop service from SCM, everything works fine i.e OnStop() method is called, but when I shutdown my PC (tried with Win 10), OnStop() or OnShutdown() method never gets called.

I did some more digging and figured out that in my machine **Fast Startup** is enabled and this configuration is causing a problem.

[image]

If I turn off fast startup then OnShutdown() method is called during shutdown but this method never gets called if I enable (turn on) fast startup.

So wanted to know that is there any other method which I can use to tackle this particular scenario? If not then how can I handle this scenario?

Comment: The best way to handle it is probably to simply not rely on these functions being called. If you ensure your service can recover correctly from being terminated, by never assuming cleanup has been performed, it ultimately doesn't matter how the process ends. There is no need for you to take care of disposing of system resources, as the OS already takes care of that. Detecting a "clean" startup would then be an optimization; this can be done by (for example) creating a file on startup and deleting it on shutdown, and assuming a clean shutdown has been performed if the file isn't there.

Comment: Outside of .NET something may be possible by accepting the `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN` control code -- this might be received even if `SHUTDOWN` is not. Unfortunately `ServiceBase` has no support for this code and there's no hook for patching it in, so not a very attractive option.